# How to start Jetty embedded HelloWorld with jetty-all.jar

Tags: jetty

I am creating a Jetty project, as a learning experience. I'm 15 and just exploring the programming world and looking to find something I like, and taking in as much information as I can along the way.

I have just started creating my Jetty server following this tutorial, http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Jetty_HelloWorld

I have reached the final step and am trying to start my server with

```
java -cp jetty-all.jar:servlet-api-2.5.jar HelloWorld
```

I am trying to run it on a Mac and this is my error message

```
Error: Could not find or load main class HelloWorld
```

Does anyone know what could be causing this? I have already compiled the HelloWorld.java file and used

```
javac -cp servlet-api-2.5.jar:jetty-all.jar HelloWorld.java
```

Can anyone help with this issue?

Thanks in advance. I just need to be pointed in the right direction here. :)

-Henry Harris

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you did the javac command as the tutorial, try this command line...

```
java -cp jetty-all.jar:servlet-api-2.5.jar:. HelloWorld
```

Notice the extra `:.` piece, that will also use the current directory to find the HelloWorld.class file.

Comment: Thanks. It worked for me too. I was trying to do this on windows machine. On windows based machines you need to that . after -cp. that is, entire command will look as follows on windows machine :

java -cp '.;jetty-all.jar:servlet-api-2.5.jar;' HelloWorld